# Django Querysets: Get only one from set and order them

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have this models:

```
#models.py

class Expression(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=254)

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Definition(models.Model):
    expression = models.ForeignKey(Expression)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=254)

class Vote(models.Model):
    definition = models.ForeignKey(Definition)
```

And this view

```
#views.py

def index(request):
    # Here is where I want to get the queryset
    return render(request, 'index.html', { 'definitions':definitions)
```

Then in the template the idea is something like this:

```
#index.html


Expression is {{ expression }}
{% for definition in expressions.definitions_set.all %}
    Country's "1" top definition for expression is {{ definition }}
    Country's "2" top definition for expression is {{ definition }}
    [etc]
{% endfor %}
```

How can I get a queryset of definitions that gets only the top definition (by votes) of each country

Answer (score 0):

[django docs link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.order_with_respect_to)

You can use `order_with_respect_to` to `Definition` for ordering.

```
class Definition(models.Model):
    expression = models.ForeignKey(Expression)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=254)

    class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to = 'country'
```

Maybe I think I can do it like above.